# Power BI - calculating duration between calls

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

`time_start` column holds start of conversation

`time_ends` column holds end of conversation, both are in time type of data in `hh:mm:ss` format

how can I calculate time duration between calls:

```
time_between_calls = time_start2 - time_end1
```

`time_start2` - start of 2nd call

`time_end1` - end of 1st call

I need to create measure which will give average of that duration for xy calls. 
I don't know how to calculate this. I guess I need some kind of temporary table where I would sort dates first. 
Any hint could be useful.

I forgot to add that I need to filter by `agent_id` first in order to get call information only for that individual agent.

So

```
FOR EACH agent_id do {
all above }
```

Comment: I think this is the kind of pattern you're looking for but with an added filter to limit the results by agent.https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/DAX-help-for-previous-row-calculation/td-p/581398

Comment: Can you give an example of the data, and is it imported or direct query. You could use a basic AVERAGE, and it the agent_id is in that same table you can slice it that way

Comment: Please provide some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've manage to solve it by following [this solution](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Blog/Mean-Time-Between-Failure-MTBF-and-Power-BI/ba-p/339586).